# VS Code JS type hint, reference type from node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I want to document a type that is defined in a node module *(`discord.js` in my case)* so that VS Code can help me with autocompletion.

VS Code supports type hints with JSDoc and this should be the correct way to document the type of the parameter `client`. Yet VS Code, when I hover over the parameter, says that it is of type `any`.

> (parameter) client: any

This is my code so far

```
module.exports = class Receiver {
    /**
     * @param {module:"discord.js".Client} client
     */
    constructor(client) {
        this.client = client
    }
}
```

How can I make VS Code understand the correct type of the parameter? It should not be `any` but `Client` instead.

PS: I have installed the `discord.js` module and can successfully use it.

Comment: If you `require('discord.js')` and assign that to a variable, say `discord`, then you should be able to use `@param {discord.Client} client` to get your type hinting.

Comment: This does work but I'd rather not have to `require('discord.js')` because of the overhead and I would not use the variable `discord` anywhere in my code. (`discord` would be an unused variable)

Comment: If you're using Closure Compiler than you'd want to define an `extern` for discord.js. With regard to defining but not using `require('discord.js)`; I agree this is the right solution, and that you should use some sort of tree shaking, whether it be Closure Compiler's "Advanced Optimizations" or Rollup, or a WebPack config, to avoid the file being bundled.

Comment: I think I can get this work this way, however I am still interested if there is a "better" solution that does not require `require('discord.js')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not official [jsdoc.app](https://jsdoc.app/) syntax, but it works for IntelliSense/TypeScript:

```js
module.exports = class Receiver {
    /**
     * @param {import("./discord.js").Client} client
     */
    constructor(client) {
        this.client = client
    }
}
```